# React native - Perform a function when user closes the app

Tags: react-native, react-native-ios

I need to run a function when the app is closed by the user.
Is there any way to catch the app closing event?

I have read the AppState API documentation but it doesn't seem to meet my needs.

Answer (score -1):

You can perform the Action in the `componentDidUnmount` function of your `App.js` component or the equivalent `useEffect(performableAction, [])` if you use afunctional component.